# How to cook for a big group

Tags: recipe-scaling, bulk-cooking

I have to prepare a meal for a group of 60 people. I already have a recipe (Japanese curry with rice) but I have no clue how many of all the ingredients I need, because when I cook it for myself I just put things in the pan without measuring anything.

So that brings me to my question:
How many ingredients do I need (in total or pp)?

The things I use in the recipe are:
- Japanese rice (separate)
- potatoes
- sweet potatoes
- big carrots
- onions

I was thinking about 100 grams of (uncooked) rice per person, so 6 kilos in total, but I have no clue how many of the other ingredients I need in the curry itself, or what amount is normal for veggies in a meal.

I will serve sausages with the meal, but separate because of the vegetarians who are attending.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! You have a couple different questions here, and you'll get much better answers if you post them as separate questions. Maybe you could ask a new question about how best to cook rice for 60 people? (When you say "the same way as small amounts" do you mean a rice cooker? Or a giant pot on the stove?) That's pretty separate from how much potato/carrot per person.

Comment: I'll post a different question on how to cook rice for 60 people, thanks!

Comment: Do you mind posting your curry recipe? This might help people answer your question.

Comment: Its almost not worth the name recipe xD I just cut the potatoes, sweet potatoes and carrots in cube like shapes, put it in a pan with water so it can cook, and then add golden curry cubes to make the curry itself. Oh, and I bake onions first, completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have time, make the dish at your normal size and measure everything you put in. This will allow you to get a recipe with proportions that you can use for your full party. Measuring weight is best if you have a scale, but volume should still be significantly better than guessing.

Say you make your dish and it uses

1. w grams potatoes
2. x grams sweet potatoes
3. y grams carrots
4. z grams onions

If this feeds 4 normal people, then for 60 people you need

1. (60 / 4) * w grams potatoes
2. (60 / 4) * x grams sweet potatoes
3. (60 / 4) * y grams carrots
4. (60 / 4) * z grams onions

Comment: Since I eat a lot in comparison to most people, I think with this way there will be to much food. Isnt there a standard portion size for things like that I can use?

Comment: This will still get you the ratios, at least, so if you figure out that you want say 40 pounds of food, you'll know how much you want of each ingredient.

Comment: The point is that I don't just want the ratio as to how much I need to cook, but also on what a normal portion (say in grams) is for a person to eat in a meal (diner in this case).

Comment: I'm sorry, english is not my mother tongue so I'm a bit out of words as to how I need to describe what I need to know.

Comment: @Noralie When you cook the small batch, estimate how many people that feeds. You can do this, for example, by seeing how much a couple of your friends eat.

Comment: @Noralie I know you want the overall quantities, but within that you'll still need the ratios, so that you know for example how many curry cubes you'll need to add to that weight of other ingredients.

Comment: @Noralie : I'm guessing there are estimates out there, but there are still issues about the people themselves, and the timing -- people might eat more at dinner vs. lunch (although in some cultures, it's the other way around); your average adult women tend to eat less than males, especially if after some strenuous activity.  Teenagers go through spurts where they'll eat you out of house & home.